# While(1) loop reduce cpu without sleep

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, cpu

my question is that i am using rawsocket passing high rate ( larger than 50kpps) traffic, two threads, one is to send ( read from buffer), another one is to receive ( write to buffer).

i have to use while(1) loop to make sure an infinite loop, and i cannot use usleep since then i will loose packet ( i have tried that)... now the cpu usage is 100% and i think i am buring my cpu...

here is the code:

```
while (1)
{

  if (sendIndex == PACKET_COUNT_MAX)
{
  sendIndex = 0;
}
  else if (ringBuffer[sendIndex].drop == 0)
{if(sendtosocket (ringBuffer, sendIndex, rawout) < 0)
    a++;
    else
    sendIndex++;}
  else if (ringBuffer[sendIndex].drop == 1) {
            ringBuffer[sendIndex].header.free = 1;
            memset (ringBuffer[sendIndex].data, 0, sizeof (ringBuffer[sendIndex].data));
            sendIndex++;
           }
  else
{
  a++;
}
    //nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 5}}, NULL);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!
Lisa

Comment: What does the send thread do when it has nothing to send? What protects the `ringBuffer` from getting clobbered by concurrent accesses?

Comment: If there is only one producer and only one consumer, a lock-free ring buffer is fairly easy.

Comment: I'm more worried by the other inefficiencies. No condvar or semaphore: CPU polling loop.  Funny memset stuff to zero buffer space, don't know why that is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the control over to the kernel. The command you may find useful is `select`. Check out the whole story on http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html. For more info, http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html.

It's all about knowing you have nothing else to do except wait for input from the network. Or the file system. Or anything else that is a file descriptor (U*ix lingo). So, you let the kernel awake you once you've got something to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Increasing the receive buffer
2. Slowing down the sendto with a sleep, that should not lose packets
3. Use the MSG_WAITALL flag with recvfrom to make it a blocking read, and make sure the socket was not opened with SOCK_NONBLOCK or O_NONBLOCK

Answer (score 0):

You need sane synchronization between your threads. This includes:

1. Using locks of some kind to ensure that a variable isn't read by one thread while it is, or might be, modified in another.
2. Using some kind of waiting scheme so that the sending thread can wait for there to be work for it do without spinning.

Check out `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_cond_wait` (assuming you're using POSIX threads).